# JavaScript - How to change input text value based on Gender Selection in Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not very well versed at `JavaScript` however, I would like to display a gender specific image URL into a input type's `hidden` field as a value. I would like the end-user to select their gender and based on that return to the input value field the URL of the corresponding Image Location. Here is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var gender;
  if (gender == 'male') {
    document.getElementById("printGender").html(value = "http://example.com/male.svg");
  } else if (gender == 'female') {
    document.getElementById("printGender").html(value = "http://example.com/female.svg");
  }
};
```

and the HTML Code:

```
<label for="name">Gender</label>
<select onchange="myFunction(event)" name="gendr" class="nofocus" id=gender required>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="printGender" style="color:#000">
```

Comment: when you define `gender` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function myFunction(listElem) 
{
  var gender = null;
  var printGenderElem = null;

  try
  {
    printGenderElem =  document.getElementById("printGender");
    gender = listElem.options[listElem.selectedIndex].value;

    if(gender=="male") printGenderElem.value="http://example.com/male.svg";
    else if(gender=="female") printGenderElem.value="http://example.com/female.svg";
    else printGenderElem.value=""

    // Debugging purposes only, remove after verified
    alert(printGenderElem.value);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert("myFunction Error:  " + e.Message);
  }
  finally
  {

  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="name">Gender</label>
<select onchange="myFunction(this)" name="gendr" class="nofocus" id=gender required>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="printGender" style="color:#000">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend using the 'this' object reference as the parameter to your function called by the 'onchange' event (this, refers to the element that calls the function, i.e. - in your case, the <select> element).

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the value of gender. Change this line:

```
var gender;
```

to:

```
var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, you never defined `gender` variable in `myFunction` so it always be `undefined` and also, your syntax for adding a `img` is COMPLETELY wrong!

Try this:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var gender = this.value; // Getting the current selected value
  if (gender == 'male') {
    document.getElementById("printGender").value = "<img src='http://example.com/male.svg'/>";
  } else if (gender == 'female') {
    document.getElementById("printGender").value = "<img src='http://example.com/female.svg'/>";
  }
};
```

Comment: I need it to be as an Input type=hidden value so as to store it as text in a database. I am not well versed at storing images on my db

Comment: Which server-sided language you are using? or is it a form?

Comment: I am using PHP and it is a registration form.

Answer (score 0):

In myfunction() the value of gender is undefined. and that is why the if-else block will never run, first capture the value, which is selected like the below code

```js
function myFunction(e) {
 var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
 if (gender == 'male'){
  document.getElementById("printGender").src="http://example.com/male.svg";
  
 } else if (gender == 'female') {
  document.getElementById("printGender").src="http://example.com/female.svg";
 }
};
```

```html
<label for="name">Gender</label>
<select onchange="myFunction(event)" name="gendr" class="nofocus" id=gender required>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
 <option value="female">Female</option>
 <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
<img id="printGender">
```